# Real Analysis, problem 1.4.22 Outer Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Exercise 22 - Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu^*$ the outer measure induced by $\mu$ according to (1.12), $M^*$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$-measurable sets, and $\overline{\mu} = \mu^*|M^*$.
>
> a.) If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\overline{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$ (Use exercise 18 found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415314/folland-real-analysis-problem-1-18))
>
> b.) In general, $\overline{\mu}$ is the saturation of the completion of $\mu$

This exercises is from Follad's Real Analysis (Section 1.4. Outer Measures).

Attempted proof a.) - Let $F\subset N$, where $N$ is a measurable null set, i.e., $N\in M$ and $\mu(N) = 0$. I will prove that $F\in M^*$. Using 18b and 18c, I believe it suffices to show that there is a $B\in \mathcal{A}_{\sigma \delta}$ such that $F\subset B$ and $\mu^*(B\setminus F) = 0$.

Since $M\subset M^*$, $N\in M^*$ and hence there exists a $C\in\mathcal{A}_{\sigma \delta}$ such that $N\subset C$ and $\mu^*(C\setminus N) = 0$. Thus $$\mu^*(C\setminus F) \leq \mu^*(C\setminus N) + \mu^*(N\setminus F) \leq \mu^*(C\setminus N) + \mu^*(N) = 0$$

I am not sure if this is completely right. Also any suggestions on part b would be greatly appreciated. I just don't understand the statement "$\overline{\mu}$ is the saturation of the completion of $\mu$".

Comment: for (a) could you show $\overline{\mathcal M}=\{E\cup F:E\in \mathcal M, \ F\subset N\text{ for some null set}N\}=\mathcal M^*$? (look at theorem 1.9 Folland). then use theorem 1.14.

Comment: @mac Didn't think of that but I believe my approach is correct as well, what do you think?

Comment: It's enought to show that $\overline{\mathcal M}=\mathcal M^*$ Since by proposition 1.13and theorem 1.14 $\overline{\mu}$ is an extension of $\mu$. If you want to show two meaures are equal then you should show that their $\sigma$-algebras are equal. However in your approach if you want to show $F\in \mathcal M^*$ it is obvious that $\mu^*(F)\leq \mu^*(N)=\mu(N)=0$ and you don't need exercise 18 in this case. indeed you need 18 to show $\overline{\mathcal M}=\mathcal M^*$

Comment: **1.** For item (a), your proof proves only that if $F\subset N$, where $N$ is a measurable null set, i.e., $N\in M$ and $\mu(N) = 0$, then $F$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.  It is an important result, but it is not what item (a) is asking to be proved.  **2.** The definition of the saturation of a measure can be found in Folland's Exercise 1.3.16.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Comment: Your answer is clean I am sure I am working on computational mathematics at the moment so I may not be able to look at your proof in detail until tonight or tomorrow ill let you know though thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Initial Remark:** This is a long exercise and it depends on some previous exercises in Folland. I made this answer as self-contained as reasonable (I explictly used  only the results Exercise 18). The definition of saturation can be found Exercise 1.3.16.

**Notation:** Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu^*$ the outer measure induced by $\mu$ according to (1.12), $M^*$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$-measurable sets, and $\overline{\mu} = \mu^*|M^*$. Let $\widehat{M}$ be the $\mu$-completion of $M$ and $\widehat{\mu} $ the completion of $\mu$.

We begin with three lemmas.

> **Lemma 1:** If $E \in M^*$ and  $\mu^*(E)< \infty$, then $E\in \widehat{M}$.

**Proof**

Let $E\subset X$ be any $\mu^*$-measurable set such that $\mu^*(E)< \infty$.

From Exercise 18-b, there exists $B\in M_{\sigma\delta} \subset M$ with $ E\subset B$ and $\mu^{*}(B\setminus E)) = 0$.
So
$$\mu^*(B)\leq \mu^*(E)+ \mu^{*}(B\setminus E))= \mu^*(E)$$
Since $ E\subset B$, we have $\mu^*(B)= \mu^*(E)$.

Now, we have that $B\setminus E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable set and  $\mu^*(B\setminus E)\leq \mu^*(B)= \mu^*(E) < \infty$. From Exercise 18-b, again, there exists $C\in M$ with $ B\setminus E\subset C$ and $\mu^{*}(C\setminus (B\setminus E)) = 0$

Define $D=C\cap B$.  Then, since $B\setminus E\subset C$, we have $B\setminus E\subset D$ and so we have
$$B\setminus D  \subset E $$
and
$$ E\setminus (B \setminus D)= E\cap D= D\setminus (B\setminus E) =  (C\setminus (B\setminus E))\cap B \subset C\setminus (B\setminus E)$$
So, since $\mu^{*}(C\setminus (B\setminus E)) = 0$,
we have
$\mu^{*}(E\setminus (B\setminus D)) = 0$.

So we have that  $D\in M$, $B\setminus D\subset E$ and $\mu^{*}(E \setminus (B\setminus D)) = 0$.

So $E =(B \setminus D) \cup (E\setminus (B\setminus D))$ where $B-D \in M$ and $\mu^{*}(E\setminus (B\setminus D)) = 0$.
So $E\in \widehat{M}$ (where $\widehat{M}$ is the $\mu$-completion of $M$).

> **Lemma 2**: For any $E\subset X$ there exists $B\in M$ such that $E\subset B$ and $\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(E)$.

**Proof**
From Exercise 18-a we know that

For any $E\subset X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $A\in M$ with $E\subset A$ and $\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(E) + \epsilon$.

So, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, let $A_n\in M$ with $E\subset A_n$ and $\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(A_n) \leq \mu^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}$.

Then let $B=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Then we have $B\in M$ and $E\subset B$. Moreover, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, $B\subset A_n$ and
$$\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(B) \leq \mu^*(A_n) \leq \mu^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}$$
So, $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(E)$.

**Remark:** $E$ don't need to be measurable. And as a consequence of item Exercise 18 item b.) $\mu^*(B\setminus E)$ may not be zero.

> **Lemma 3:** If $A \in \widehat{M}$, then $A \in M^*$ and $\mu^*(A)=\widehat{\mu}(A)$.

**Proof:**

Let $A\in \widehat{M}$. So $A =B\cup C$ , where $B\in M$ and $C\subset N$ such that $N \in M$ and $\mu(N)=0$. In particular, we have $0 \leq \mu^*(C)\leq \mu^*(N)=\mu(N)=0$. So $\mu^*(C)=0$ and it follows that $C$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. So we have $A =G\cup H$, $B\in M \subset M^*$ and $C\in M^*$. So $A\in M^*$. Moreover
$$\mu*(B) \leq \mu^*(A) \leq \mu*(B) + \mu*(C) = \mu*(B)$$
So
$$\mu^*(A)= \mu*(B)= \mu(B)=\widehat{\mu}(A)$$

> **Exercise 22** - Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, $\mu^*$ the outer measure induced by $\mu$ according to (1.12), $M^*$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$-measurable sets, and $\overline{\mu} = \mu^*|M^*$.
>
> a.) If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\overline{\mu}$ is the completion of $\mu$ (Use exercise 18 found [here][1])
>
> b.) In general, $\overline{\mu}$ is the saturation of the completion of $\mu$

**Proof:**

**a.)** Suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Then there is $\{X_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ family of disjoint sets, such that, for all $i$, $\mu(X_i)<+\infty$ and $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$.

Let $E\subset X$ be any $\mu^*$-measurable set. Then, we define, for all $i$, $E_i=E\cap X_i$, we have that $\{E_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family of disjoint sets, such that, for all $i$, $\mu(X_i)<+\infty$ and $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$.

From the lemma 1, for all $i$, $E_i\in \widehat{M}$ (where $\widehat{M}$ is the $\mu$-completion of $M$).

Since  $\widehat{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $E = E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i \in \widehat{M}$.

**b.)** Let $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}$ be the saturation of the completion of $\mu$. We know that $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}$ is defined on
$$\widetilde{\widehat{M}}= \{E : E \textrm{ is ${\widehat{\mu}}$-locally measurable} \} $$
On the other hand, $\overline{\mu}$ is defined on $M^*$. We want to prove that $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}=\overline{\mu}$.

We begin by  proving that $\widetilde{\widehat{M}}=M^*$, it means, we begin by proving that $E$ is ${\widehat{\mu}}$-locally measurable if and only if $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $E$ is ${\widehat{\mu}}$-locally measurable.
For any  $B \in M$ such that $\mu(B)<+\infty$, we have $B\in \widehat{M}$ and $$\widehat{\mu}(B)=\mu(B)<\infty$$

So $B\in \widehat{M}$ and $\widehat{\mu}(B)<\infty$. Since $E$ is ${\widehat{\mu}}$-locally measurable, we have that $E\cap B \in \widehat{M}$. So, by lemma 3, $E\cap B \in M^*$. And we also have $E^c\cap B= B \setminus  (E\cap B) \in M^*$.

So we have proved that $B \in M$ and  $\mu(B)<+\infty$, then $E\cap B \in M^*$ and $E^c\cap B \in M^*$

Now let us check the $\mu*$-measurability of $E$. Let $A\subset X$. If $\mu^*(A)=\infty$, we trivially have
$$\mu^*(A) \geq \mu*(E\cap A)+\mu*(E^c\cap A)$$
If $\mu^*(A)<\infty$ then using lemma 2, we have $B\in M$ such that $A\subset B$ and $\mu(B)=\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(A)<\infty$.  So we have that $E\cap B \in M^*$ and $E^c\cap B \in M^*$ and
$$\mu^*(A)= \mu^*(B) = \mu^*(E\cap B ) + \mu^*(E^c\cap B) \geq \mu^*(E\cap A ) + \mu^*(E^c\cap A)$$

So E is $\mu^*$-measurable.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose E is $\mu^*$-measurable. For any  $A\in \widehat{M}$ such that $\widehat{\mu}(A)<+\infty$. By lemma 3,  $A\in M^*$ and $\mu*(A)= \widehat{\mu}(A)<+\infty$. So $E\cap A\in M^*$ and $\mu*(E\cap A)\leq \mu^*(A)<+\infty$. So by lemma 1, $E \cap A \in \widehat{M}$. So, $E$ is ${\widehat{\mu}}$-locally measurable.

So we have proved $\widetilde{\widehat{M}}=M^*$.

Now we must prove that $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}$ coincides to $\overline{\mu}$.

Since the extension of $\mu$ to  $\widehat{M}$ (the completion of $\mu$) is unique, we have for all $E \in \widehat{M}$,
$$ \widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}(E)= \overline{\mu}(E)= \widehat{\mu}(E) $$

If $E\in \widetilde{\widehat{M}} \setminus \widehat{M}$, then by definition of $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}$, we have $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}(E)=+\infty$. Note $E\in \widetilde{\widehat{M}} \setminus \widehat{M}= M^*\setminus \widehat{M}$ and, by lemma 1, we have $\mu^*(E)=+\infty$, that is $\overline{\mu}(E)=\mu^*(E)=+\infty$. So,  $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}(E)=\overline{\mu}(E)$.

So we have proved that $\widetilde{\widehat{\mu}}=\overline{\mu}$.

Comment: Are the lemmas you present results from exercise 18?

Comment: @Wolfy , Lemma 1 and lemma 2 are consequence of exercise 18 (items a and b).  Of course, we can prove lemma 1 and lemma 2 without using exercise 18. In this case the proofs would be a little bit longer (since we would have to redo, at least partially, the work done prove exercise 18a and 18b).  Lemma 3 does not use exercise 18.

Comment: Ok, I see (not really). You seem pretty good at this stuff, are you possibly interested in tutoring via skype for $$?

Comment: @Wolfy , Note that lemma 2 is an important result, which is useful to prove several other results in Measure Theory. The set $B$ whose existence is stated in lemma 2 is called a "mensurable cover" of $E$.

Note that lemma 1 and  lemma 3 are kind of reciprocal to each other. Together, they describe the relationship between $M^*$ and $\widehat{M}$.

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, I may be interested in tutoring via skype. We can try.

Comment: Ok when would be available and how much do you charge?

Comment: Ok, when would you want to meet on skype? just sent you a request my skype name is vuulfgang

Comment: @Wolfy , it can be right now, if you are available. If not, we can schedule some other time today.

Comment: Alright ill skype you now

Comment: Do you know how to prove b for this question by chance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796546/real-analysis-folland-problem-1-4-24-outer-measures