# Real Analysis, Folland problem 1.4.24 Outer Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X,M)$, and let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\mu$. Suppose that $E\subset X$ satisfies $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(X)$ (but not that $E\in M$).
>
> a.) If $A,B\in M$ and $A\cap E = B\cap E$ then $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$
>
> b.) Let $M_{E} = \{ A \cap E: A\in M\}$, and define the function $\nu$ on $M_E$ defined by $\nu(A\cap E) = \mu(A)$ (which makes sense by (a)). Then $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\nu$ is a measure on $M_E$.

Attempted proof a.) Suppose $A,B\in M$ and $A\cap E = B\cap E$ where $E\subset X$. Since $\mu$ is finite on $(X,M)$ then $\mu(X) < \infty$ and we have $\mu(X) = \mu(A\cup A^c) = \mu(B\cup B^c)$. Note that $$\mu(A) + \mu(A^c\cap B) = \mu(A\cup B) = \mu(B) + \mu(B^c\cap A)$$ by symmetry, so it suffices to show that $\mu(A^c\cap B) = 0$.

We have that $E\subset A\cup B^c = (A^c\cap B)^c$. So $$\mu(X) = \mu^*(X) = \mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*((A^c\cap B)^c) = \mu((A^c\cap B)^c) = \mu(X) - \mu(A^c\cap B)$$ and hence $\mu(A^c\cap B) = 0$.

Attempted solution b.) Let $M_E = \{A\cap E: A\in M\}$ and define a function $\nu$ on $M_E$ defined by $\nu(A\cap E) = \mu(A)$. To show that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra I believe we have to first show that it is an algebra and in doing so we have to show that $M_E$ is closed under finite unions and complements. Then once we have shown that $M_E$ is an algebra we have to show that it is closed under countable unions or countable intersections to show that it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am stuck here any suggestions on this part is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have $A \cap E = B \cap E$, so $(A \cap E) = (A\cap E) \cap (B \cap E) = (A \cap B \cap E)$, and $(A\setminus B) \cap E = \varnothing = (B\setminus A) \cap E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok, I think this helps what I started doing. Is there anything incorrect in terms of what I have written down above?

Comment: I didn't see a mistake. Whether what you have helps is a different question. (Which I'd have to think about to answer, don't see it immediately.)

Comment: Ok, good to know

Comment: @DanielFischer I need some help with this if your still around

Comment: Since $A,B \in M$, we have $A^c \cap B \in M$. And for all $D \in M$, the additivity of $\mu$ gives $\mu(X) = \mu(D \cup D^c) = \mu(D) + \mu(D^c)$, so by finiteness $\mu(D^c) = \mu(X) - \mu(D)$. Apply that to $D = A^c\cap B$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand up until you say apply that to $D = A^c\cap B$ what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you replace $D$ with $(A^c\cap B)$ in $\mu(D^c) = \mu(X) - \mu(D)$ you get $\mu((A^c\cap B)^c) = \mu(X) - \mu((A^c \cap B))$.

Comment: ok I see now thank you

Comment: @DanielFischer any suggestions for b?

Comment: Start with showing that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. That's a straightforward verification. Can you do that?

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought we would have to show that it is an algebra? If not then we have to show that it is closed under countable unions or intersections. I am not sure if I can do that

Comment: Take the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra (note that the universe here is $E$). What are the conditions for a family of subsets of $E$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra? Check each of the conditions for $M_E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The definition of a $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra that is closed under countable unions or intersections. I am not sure how to answer your other question..

Comment: That's one way to define a $\sigma$-algebra. Okay, take that. Start by verifying that $M_E$ is an algebra of subsets of $E$. What do you have to do for that?

Comment: @DanielFischer If $E\subset X$ then a nonempty collection $E$ of $X$ denoted $M_E$ is an algebra if it is closed under finite unions and complements?

Comment: @DanielFischer its been about 5 hours or more to do one problem for me. Maybe you could provide a proof of b?

Comment: @DanielFischer please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X,M)$, and let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\mu$. Suppose that $E\subset X$ satisfies $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(X)$ (but not that $E\in M$).
>
> a.) If $A,B\in M$ and $A\cap E = B\cap E$ then $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$
>
> b.) Let $M_{E} = \{ A \cap E: A\in M\}$, and define the function $\nu$ on $M_E$ defined by $\nu(A\cap E) = \mu(A)$ (which makes sense by (a)). Then $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\nu$ is a measure on $M_E$.

Before we proceed to the proof, it is worth to understand the idea in this exercise. Given a finite measure $\mu$ on $(X,M)$, and $E \subseteq X$, we want to "restrict $\mu$ to $E$".

Suppose $E\in M$. First we need to restrict $M$ to $E$. The way to do it is very natural, we define
$$M_{E} = \{ A : A\in M \text{ and } A\subseteq E\}$$
and we define, for all $A\in M_E$, $\nu(A)=\mu(A)$. It is easy to prove that $M_E$ is a a $\sigma$-algebra and $\nu$ is a measure.

Now, what happens if $E$ is not measurable ($E\notin M$)? In this case, $M_E$ as previously defined may reduce to just $\{\emptyset\}$ and $E$ surely will not be in  $M_E$ ($M_E$ is no longer a $\sigma$-algebra). So, "restriction of a measure" to a non-measurable set, in general, does not work.

However, IF $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(X)$, we can adjust our definitions and have a similar result. We define
$$M_{E} = \{ A \cap E: A\in M\}$$
and, for all $A\cap E\in M_E$,  $\nu(A\cap E)=\mu(A)$
Then we need to prove that  $M_{E}$ is a  $\sigma$-algebra and that $\nu$ is a measure. The first step to prove  $\nu$ is a measure is to prove that $\nu$ is well defined. So we must prove that, if $A, B\in M$ and $A \cap E =B \cap E$, then $\nu(A \cap E)=\nu(A \cap E)$, that is, $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.
(That is why we need item a. in the exercise).

Now let us proceed to the proof.

**Proof:**

**a.)** Suppose $A,B\in M$ and $A\cap E = B\cap E$. Then
$$(A \setminus B) \cap E = A\cap B^c \cap E = (A\cap E)  \cap B^c = (B\cap E)  \cap B^c = \emptyset$$
So $A \setminus B \subseteq E^c$, so $E \subseteq (A \setminus B )^c$, and we have, using that $(A \setminus B )^c\in M$ ,
$$\mu(X)=\mu^*(E)\leqslant \mu^*((A \setminus B )^c) = \mu((A \setminus B )^c)\leqslant \mu(X)$$
So, we have $ \mu((A \setminus B )^c) =\mu(X)$.

On the other hand, we have that $\mu(X)=\mu(A \setminus B ) +\mu((A \setminus B )^c)$. So we get
$$\mu(X)=\mu(A \setminus B ) +\mu(X)$$
Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have $ \mu(A \setminus B )=0$

In a similar way, we can prove that $ \mu(B \setminus A )=0$.

Now, note that
$$\mu(A)=\mu(A)+0=\mu(A)+\mu(B \setminus A )=\mu(A\cup B ) = \mu(B)+\mu(A \setminus B )= \mu(B)+0=\mu(B)$$
So, we have $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

**b.)** It is straight forward to check that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$. From item a, we know that $\nu$ is well defined. It is straight forward to check it is in fact a measure.

$M_{E} = \{ A \cap E: A\in M\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

i. Since $\emptyset \in M$, $\emptyset = \emptyset \cap E \in M_{E}$.

ii. Given any $B\in M_{E}$, there is $A \in M$ such that $B=A \cap E$ then
$$E\setminus B = E \setminus (A\cap E) = (X\setminus A) \cap E$$
Since $X\setminus A \in M$, we have that $E\setminus B \in M_{E}$.

iii. Given any countable family $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of sets in  $M_{E}$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is $A_n \in M$ such that $B_n=A_n \cap E$. So
$$ \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (A_n \cap E) = \left( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right)\cap E$$
Since $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in M$, we have that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n \in M_{E}$.

So we have proved $M_{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$.

Now, let us prove that the function $\nu$ on $M_E$ defined by $\nu(A\cap E) = \mu(A)$ is a measure on $M_E$.

First, note that, as a consequence of item a, $\nu$  is well defined as a function.

Since $\emptyset=\emptyset \cap E$, we have
$$\nu(\emptyset)=\nu(\emptyset \cap E)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$$

Second, given any countable family $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of **disjoint** sets in  $M_{E}$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is $A_n \in M$ such that $B_n=A_n \cap E$.  Note that the sets $A_n$ may not be disjoint.

Let, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $C_{n}=A_{n} \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} A_i$, (note that $C_0=A_0$). Then, we have that the sets $C_n$ are **disjoint** sets in $M$, and we also have

$$  C_n\cap E= \left( A_{n} \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} A_i  \right)\cap E= (A_{n}\cap E) \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} (A_i \cap E)= B_n \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i = B_n$$
the last step holds because $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family  of **disjoint** sets.

So, by the definition of $\nu$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\nu(B_n) = \nu(C_n\cap E)= \mu(C_n) \tag{1}$$
and we also have that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n \in M$ and
$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (C_n \cap E)=\left ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n \right) \cap E$$
So we have, using $(1)$,
$$\nu \left ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n  \right) =  \nu \left (\left ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n \right) \cap E\right)= \mu\left ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_n \right) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu(C_n)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \nu(B_n) $$

Comment: I have part (a) down now but for (b) I am not sure how to show that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I looked online and they said the same thing that it is easy to see that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra but I do not find it so easy unfortunately

Comment: Take $A_i\in M$ then $A_i\cap E\in M_E$, now $\cup A_i\cap E=(\cup A_i)\cap E=A\cap E$ for $A=\cup A_i$ which is in $M$ and so $\cup A_i\cap E$ is in $M_E$. Do the same for intersections

Comment: @Wolfy , I included a detailed proof that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Wolfy , You don't need to prove $M_E$ is closed by countable intersections. It is a consequence of being a $\sigma$-algebra. But if you want a direct proof that $M_E$ is closed by countable intersections, it will be very similar to the proof of countable unions.

Comment: @Wolfy, Given any countable family $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of sets in  $M_{E}$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is $A_n \in M$ such that $B_n=A_n \cap E$. So 
$$ \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n= \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (A_n \cap E) = \left( \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right)\cap E$$
Since $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in M$, we have that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n \in M_{E}$.

Comment: I see so the three points you show that $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra what are they called. What is the definition of $\sigma$-algebra are you using?

Comment: I am not sure how to show that $\nu$ is a measure. I can see that $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$ but I am not sure how to show that if $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset M$, pairwise disjoint then $$\nu\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j\right) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\nu(E_j)$$

Comment: @Wolfy, Yes, there are different (equivalent) ways to define $\sigma$-algebra. Here I am using one of them. See for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra

Comment: @Wofy OK. I will add a detailed proof that  $\nu$ is a measure. One moment, please.

Comment: Ok, thank you as an aside. This problem has taken me nearly 6 hours to complete, should I be worried?

Comment: @Wolfy I added a detailed proof that $\nu$ is a measure.

Comment: Does $\{B_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ have to be countable or does it suffice to just let be disjoint?

Comment: Also, I sent you an email :)

Comment: @Wolfy , For the sake of proving $\nu$ is a measure, $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$  must be a countable family of disjoint sets. (A busy day today.  I've got e-mail. I'll answer you).

Comment: I am going back over 1.4 now and I am confused how $$E\setminus (A\cap E) = (X\setminus A)\cap E$$ It seems to me that one could just say $$E\cap (A\cap E)^c = (E\cap A^c)\cup (E\cap E^c) = (E\cap A^c)$$ since we know that $A\in M$ then $A^c\in M$ and $E\in M$ so then it should be the case that $E\setminus B\in M_{E}$?

Comment: @Wolfy  1. Please note that $A^c=X\setminus A$.  2. Since $A \in M$ then $A^c \in M$  and since $E \setminus B = A^c \cap E$, we have that  $E \setminus B \in M_E$ (see the definition of $M_E$).  3. Please note that we can NOT assume $E \in M$.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a) you want to show that $A^c\cap B=B\setminus A$ has measure zero. Well note that $E\subset A\cup B^C$, this will give you the result you want by using your sets.

Part (b) is pretty straightfowrward, it might be useful to prove additivity to look at $\overline A_i=A_i\setminus \cup_{j<i} A_i$ where $A_i\cap E$ is a disjoint family, since then $\overline A_i\cap E=A_i\cap E$.

Comment: How can $\mu^*(E) = 0$? Is there anything in my question in regards to the sets and stuff incorrect?

Comment: By the way what would $\mu(A\cup B)$ equal in regards to the question I posted?

Comment: If $E$ isn't measurable, then $\mu^{\ast}(X \setminus E) > 0$.

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning for (a). I am sure you are right but I don't see it

Comment: You have: $\mu(X)=\mu^*(X)=\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(A\cup B^c)=\mu^*((A^c\cap B)^c)=\mu((A^c\cap B)^c)=\mu(X)-\mu(B\setminus A)$ and so is zero.

Comment: Can you see what I edited I am sure it is wrong but just want to check with you

Comment: Nevermind it is completely wrong

Comment: Spotty can you take what I have started and combined with your genius get the result for (a)?

Comment: In you question now the following is wrong: $A\cap E=B\cap E$ does not imply $A\cap B=A\cap B\cap E$ (just take $A=B$ and $E$ anything else). Anyway so building on my previous comment: $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(A^C\cap B)$ and do the same for $B$, then you get $\mu(A)=\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(B)$ and you are done

Comment: I don't see how $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(A^c\cap B)$

Comment: Never mind I see how that is the case now

Comment: Please see edited question

Comment: that is just because: $(A^c\cap B)^c=X\setminus A^c\cap B$

Comment: @Spotty please help me with b could you extend your answer to include a proof?

Comment: @Spotty If this would incentivize you I will accept your answer if you show me how to prove b.

Comment: Taking intersections with $E$ commutes with union and intersection so $M_E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra since $M$ was. Now the measure is well defined by part $A$ and is always non-negative since $\mu$ is and is zero on the empty set. To show that it is additive use that sets $\overline A_i$ in my answer in order to use additivity of $\mu$.