# Complete Measures and Complete Sigma Algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The version of Caratheodory's Theorem in Folland proceeds as follows:

> If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$, the collection $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mu^*$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, and the restriction of $\mu^*$ to $\mathcal{M}$ is a complete measure.

Suppose I have a $A \subset X$ and $\mu^*(A)=0$. Is this enough for $A \in \mathcal{M}$? I'm working on a problem and a solution uses this fact by saying "$\mu^*$ is complete" -- but this is a property of the measure, not the sigma algebra. Caratheodory's theorem says nothing about the completion of $\mathcal{M}$

The relevant question is here (part b, proving the reverse direction):
[Folland, Real Analysis problem 1.18](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415314/folland-real-analysis-problem-1-18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes! Suppose that $\mu^*(A)=0$ for $A\subset X$. Then $\mu^*(E\cap A)\leq \mu^*(A)$, thus $\mu^*(E\cap A) = 0$ for every $E\subset X$. From this
$$
\mu^*(E)\geq \mu^*(E\setminus A) = \mu^*(E\setminus A) + 0 = \mu^*(E\setminus A) + \mu^*(E\cap A).
$$
The inequality
$$
\mu^*(E)\leq \mu^*(E\setminus A) + \mu^*(E\cap A)
$$
is obvious, thus we have
$$
\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E\setminus A) + \mu^*(E\cap A)
$$
for every $E\subset X$, which means that $A\in\mathcal{M}$.