# Understand solution of Folland 1.18 exercise

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the exercise which is described and solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415314/folland-real-analysis-problem-1-18)

But I cannot understand the following claim:

In bullet (a) op says:

Since $$ \mu^{*}\left(A_{j}\right)=\inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_{0}\left(B_{k}^{j}\right)\thinspace:\thinspace A_{j}\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{k}^{j}\thinspace\thinspace,\thinspace\left\{ B_{k}^{j}\right\} _{k=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathcal{A}\right\}  $$

We have $$ \mu^{*}\left(A_{j}\right)\leq\mu_{0}\left(A_{j}\right)+2^{-j}\varepsilon $$

Why is this true? cannot see it.

Also, in bullet b, how come this is correct?

[image]

Shouldnt it be $\mu^{*}(B_n \cap E)$ instead  $\mu^{*}(E)$ ? (and then the equality does not hold..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the definitions; I am not going to go search them to solve your doubts.

Comment: @WilliamM. I think anyone who's capable to answer this is already familiar with outer measure definition